# Protractor - Best way to select a related element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Ive just started using protractor and want to be able to select the parent element of a child element where the child element contains certain text. So Given the HTML below

```
<ul class="content">
   <li ng-if="case.taskStatus.outstanding &gt; 0" has-permission="task.get" class="task-list ng-scope" ng-repeat="case in cases">
    <h3 class="ng-binding">Case #7000-0000-1060</h3>
    <ul>
      <li error-msg="task.errorMessages.status" error-handler="" ng-if="task.status != 'Completed'" class="task-list-task ng-scope" ng-repeat="task in case.tasks">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">Create physical case file</h4>
        <h4 class="ng-binding"></h4>
        <p>
            <span ng-show="task.assignee" class="ng-binding">Assigned to case viewer</span>
            |
            <span ng-show="task.dueDate" class="ng-binding">To be completed by 28 November 2014</span>
        </p>

        <ul class="task-actions">
            <li has-permission="task-assign.put" class="icon-button">
                <a confirmation-message="task.name" confirmation-type="'task'" opg-click-confirmation="markAsComplete(case.caseId, task, case.tasks, cases)" class="opg-icon ng-isolate-scope" href="">Complete <span class="accessible-text ng-binding">Create physical case file</span></a>
            </li>
            <li has-permission="task-unassign.put" class="icon-button">
                <a ng-click="selectForAllocation(case.caseId, task, case.tasks)" ng-class="{ active: task.selected }" class="opg-icon" href="">Allocate <span class="accessible-text ng-binding">Create physical case file</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li><
</ul>
```

I want to be able to select the a link that has the span inside it with the text "Create physical case file". It seems like this should be possible with the addLocator method of protractor to write a custom function to return that element. http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator

Is there another way to do it or should I just used the addLocator method.

Comment: If your HTML code is "fixed" (not expected to change when the user interacts with it), then you already know what the parent element is.  Just give it an (example here) `id="parent"` attribute, and then use `var parnt=document.getElementById("parent");` to access it.  Or am I missing something in terms of what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I prefer not to use xpath, but this is something that may solve your problem:

```
// Select an element by css + text. Then get the parent.
element(by.cssContainingText('h4', 'Create physical case file'))
  .element(by.xpath('..'))
  .element(by.XXX) // get anything below the parent
```